# Convert Excel VBA app to Sharepoint 2010 Online

Tags: web-application

My company has an Excel VBA app that they want to be convert to Sharepoint.

Basically it has 6 buttons on a spreadsheet, which each take you to another sheet that asks you a series of multiple-choice questions. Once you've completed a section, you hit submit and it takes you back to the 6 buttons. When you have done all 6 sections, it does some behind the scenes calculations and presents you a series of spider charts summarising the results.

Any suggestion on the best way to Sharepointify something like this? I have Infopath 2010 and Sharepoint 2010 Online.

Thanks,

JT

Comment: What problems does the existing app pose you? Why do you need to convert this into a SharePoint app?

Comment: I ask this, because you may want to re-engineer something in SharePoint that satisfies what the app is meant to do, rather than wasting A LOT of time trying to re-produce the look and feel (which is all you've described) in SharePoint.

Comment: I'm not too bothered about retaining the exact look and feel. In fact the desire to put it on Sharepoint is to make it more easily available, and to enable it to have a nicer look and feel. It may not end up being Sharepoint, it could be something running on IIS on our server, but I wonder if Sharepoint may be able to do a job?

Comment: It can do, start off with the Survey list as suggested in one of the answers below. See what's immediately customisable and find out what the limitations are.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use sharepoint OOTB? goto the following:

"Site Actions" then "Create" look for "Survey" under "Tracking"

You can create a list and customise it how you want :)